# Did the Black Panther score use Didgeridoos?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, soundtrack, black-panther

I tried to google, but couldn't really find any help.

In the track "Waterfall Fight" on the Black Panther score (not the soundtrack), I could swear it sounds like they used didgeridoos. I know the composer was going for the "tribal" feel, which makes sense, but it just takes me out of the track a little bit, given that didgeridoos are Australian tribal, not African.

So I was wondering either
a) were they, in fact, didgeridoos? or
b) is there some African tribal instrument that sounds similar to didgeridoos?

[Here is the bit I am referring to](https://youtu.be/xYu6Jk36pKA?t=27).

Comment: needs a link that can be seen in all territories.

Comment: :( Not sure how to find that on youtube.

Comment: me neither, but that link just has the "nope, you can't do that from here" logo

Comment: Given the effort Göransson (w/Coogler) put into researching traditional African music I would be surprised if a non-traditionally African instrument were used in the score. In several interviews, Göransson states specifically how he wanted to create a sound with traditional African instruments (e.g. touring w/Baaba Maal and from early recordings held the International Library of African Music, Grahamstown, SA). There's a great interview with Göransson  https://pitchfork.com/thepitch/how-black-panther-composer-ludwig-goransson-found-the-sound-of-wakanda-interview/?mbid=social_twitter

Answer (score 4):

That's a low brass instrument. Doesn't need to be a didgeridoo specifically. In fact, that sample sounds more in-tune than typical of a didgeridoo. I'm closing out with examples of didgeridoo and a possible African instrument:

"Musicologists classify [the didgeridoo] as a brass aerophone."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didgeridoo

"The kakaki trumpet is a long musical instrument, played by the indigenous members of the hausa/fulani communities in Northern Nigeria. The one in this video was played at the Gong Palace, Kagoma, Kaduna State, Nigeria."